# Animate Marker Change Position in Xamarin.Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to animate change marker position in Xamarin android Google Map

```
var markerWithIcon = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerWithIcon.SetPosition(new LatLng(e.Latitude, e.Longitude));
var marker = googleMap.AddMarker(markerWithIcon);
```

Setting its position

```
 marker.Position = new LatLng(e.Latitude, e.Longitude);
```

How to change position with linear animation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Android API versions are you targeting?

Comment: API Level 19 and above